# Click Radio to clear selection

Tags: reactjs

I have forked:
https://codesandbox.io/s/uncheck-radio-forked-xhkt4g?file=/demo.js

This works well in that you can check the radio again to clear - but you will see that I am simulating this within a map for example, whereby there are multiple rows with the same checkboxes.

Clicking one will tick the other same value radio and visa versa.

How can I implement this within a map when the values are the same for each row of items?

Answer (score 0):

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/uncheck-radio-forked-4xubmn?file=/demo.js)

data stored in state `data`

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt allow me to untick the radio? If the radio is checked, then I want to give the user to click again to uncheck it

Comment: Thank you ... can that be made any simpler?

Comment: I don't think I can made it simpler

Comment: No worries - was hoping for a solution to bind to the handleClick